# What is the upper bound for the worst case of quick sort using the middle element as pivot?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

What is the tightest upper bound for the worst case of quick sort if you are picking the middle element (the element in the middle position, not the median) as the pivot?

Comment: Middle as in median or the item in the middle position?

Comment: Worst case is always n square, if by middle element you mean the median element then it is not worst case anymore

Comment: Item in the middle position not the median..

Comment: Please remember to show your attempt at solving the problem when asking a question.

Comment: O(n^2) is the upper bound of for the quick sort worst case but what does  is "tighest upper bound" means??

Answer (score 1):

A deterministic quicksort using a linear-time median pivot selection (and @n.m.'s comment) has O(n log n) worst case performance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Selection-based_pivoting

Comment: You can always partition your array in three, `<pivot`, `==pivot` and `>pivot`.

Comment: "A deterministic quick sort always has a O(n^2) worst case." - so does one using randomness, it's just that one can't construct said worst-case unless you know the 'random' numbers to be generated (i.e. the seed of a PRNG). Though I'm not really sure why you mentioned your example input as the worst case, as it also would be if using randomness, and it's not the worst-case using a well-known optimization taking advantage of duplication.

Comment: @n.m. You're right, I forgot this obvious trick. Using the linear-time median selection algorithm you get O(n log n) then.

Comment: @Dukeling My previous statement wasn't true. O(n log n) is the worst case if you are using a linear time median selection algorithm and n.m.'s comment.

Comment: You answer post-edit doesn't answer the question anymore. The "middle element" is referring to the "Item in the middle position, not the median" (as per comment).

Answer (score 0):

If middle element you mean the median of the input array then the time complexity for even the worst case is `O(nlogn)` but if you mean the middle element of unsorted array then it is `O(n^2)` in worst case because it can cause an unbalanced partition in worst case 0:n-1. But in average case it will still be `O(nlogn)`

Answer (score 0):

Worst case performans of quick sort is O(nˆ2). Average case is O(nlogn).

O(nˆ2) is upper bound for worst case.
O(nlogn) is tight bound for expected case.